# Why in Oracle 11gR2 I can't drop the materialized view with the same user that created it?

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, materialized-view

I created a materialized view with the `DI_TEST_AL` user, let's name it `MY_MVIEW`. It appears in the `USER_OBJECTS` table as `MATERIALIZED VIEW`, I try to drop it, I get a success message, but the object is still there. In fact if I try to re-create it I get an error like "object already exists".

I see that there is a table with the same name belonging to another schema. I assume that should not cause the problem, but I felt like mentioning it.

Here is the SQL*Plus output:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Mon Aug 1 17:01:50 2011

SQL> select object_name, object_type, owner from all_objects where object_name = 'MY_MVIEW';  
OBJECT_NAME OBJECT_TYPE       OWNER
----------- ----------------- ----------
MY_MVIEW    MATERIALIZED VIEW DI_TEST_AL
MY_MVIEW    TABLE             DIDEV11

SQL> DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW MY_MVIEW;
Materialized view dropped.

SQL> select object_name, object_type, owner from all_objects where object_name = 'MY_MVIEW';
OBJECT_NAME OBJECT_TYPE       OWNER
----------- ----------------- ----------
MY_MVIEW    MATERIALIZED VIEW DI_TEST_AL
MY_MVIEW    TABLE             DIDEV11

SQL>
```

I double checked my permission and `DROP ALL MATERIALIZED VIEWS` is granted to the `DI_TEST_AL` user.

Comment: what is `DO_OPP_SEARCH_MVIEW`?

Comment: If you want to drop the MY_MVIEW materialized view, drop it like so: DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW MY_MVIEW. ATM, you're dropping something else, and it might be critical...

Comment: I'm trying to drop MY_MVIEW, I changed the name in the example for brevity but I forgot that bit... Any idea how to debug this? Why oracle says it's dropped but it's not? Cheers

Comment: Do you have a support contract? there is some 10g bugs which cause what you are seeing, perhaps they are stil around. I tried to replicate against 11gR2 but was unable to. Perhaps provide a complete script from initial table and MV which others can try to replicate.

Comment: Try to include `STATUS` in the select on `ALL_OBJECTS`. I have also this problem, and for me, status on the materialized view is `INVALID`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Connect as sysdba and check if there is any entires in dba_summaries for the MV. If there is run,

```
drop summary <OWNER>.<MV_NAME>;`
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that was preventing the materialized view to be removed completely...

Comment: I have this exact problem, and the MV was listed in `dba_summaries`. The problem is when I try to run `DROP SUMMARY MY_OWNER.MY_MATERIALIZED_VIEW;`, I get error **ORA-00950 ... invalid DROP option**.

Comment: @awe try to connect your database as / sysdba. Then you can use DROP SUMMARY command.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue when i tried to drop materialized view it says View doesn't exist. If I try to create it, it says Name already exists. 
This is a bug in Oracle.

Before dropping view, query on all_objects table.

SQL : SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME ='MY_MVIEW';
It should return 2 records, ojbect_type = TABLE and Object_type = MATERIALIZED VIEW.

But if its showing only one record with Object_type = Table then drop that table from database

Drop table MY_MVIEW;

And try to re-create the materialized view. It should work.